# How to connect to a NestJS microservice running on AWS using ClientProxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, nestjs, serverless-framework

Given I have a [NestJS Microservice](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics) (created with `NestFactory.createMicroservice`) deployed as Lambda + API Gateway in AWS by Serverless framework. How can I connect to it from my NestJS HTTP Api using the ClientProxy class?

I have succesfully connected to it using Websocket King so I know it works however I can't see a WSS Transport option for the NestJS [Client Proxy](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#client).

I've tried using Transport.TCP to the API Gateway directly and I get a NOT FOUND exception, e.g:

```
ClientsModule.register([
  {
    name: dataApiClientToken,
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
      host: 'xxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev',
      port: 80
    }
  },
])
```

To give some context, My architectural plan was to have a microservice specifically for database operations (TypeORM etc) that was called by a NestJS HTTP API. I assumed it would work with ClientProxy? If this assumption is wrong, should I instead be using a [Websocket Gateway](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways)?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @J-Krush Ended Long time ago since I looked at this but I think I came to the conclusion that attempting to host the microservice on a lamda was not possible, I.E TCP connection through Gateway won't work. If you host it on an EC2 you'll probably be ok. For servless solution youre best to use the Websocket approach instead of microservice.